# Same sound overlapping making it very loud. Tips/Tricks?

Tags: c#, audio, xna

I've got multiple object in a game I'm making, and I'm having major issues figuring out how to play sounds without playing the *same* sound twice or more. I'm wondering if you have any tricks/tips on how to make the sound play only once no matter how many instances of it is made and be balanced, rather than having it played 50 times being mega loud.

I'm using the XNA.Framework.Audio.SoundEffectInstance to play sounds.

Comment: Edited the question to clarify issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a mixing issue than a programming issue.  Playing a sample twice will always result in a fuller effect.

From a programmatic perspective, you can make sure the sound is never playing twice at the same time.  To accomplish this, set a boolean value every time a sound is about to play.  Before you play the sound, make sure the boolean value is false or cancel the event.  Set the boolean value to false once the sound is played.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty generic answer, but maybe you can create different sound classes (for example, shooting sounds, moving sounds, environment sounds).

When you play your sounds, you could play the current sound of each class while muting all the other sounds of that class.

For example, for every gunshot, it might be the case that the time in between each shot is shorter than the time it takes to play the sound. For each new gunshot, just mute all the other sounds in the pool of shooting sounds.

To do this, you might add a shooting sound object into a shooting sounds array, and for every game frame, check to make sure that there is no new sound. If there's a new sound, iterate through the array of sounds to mute everything before playing your new sound.

You can then make multiple arrays of sounds (walking/environment) so that your shooting sounds don't cut out walking sounds/environment sounds.

Comment: This sounds unnecessarily complicated, I think there is a simpler way. Thanks for sharing your thoughts though! :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the instance class you could make a static variable that is a boolean.

When an instance goes to make the sound, first have it check the static variable.  If the variable is true, don't play the sound.  If it is false, play the sound.

When the sound is done playing, turn the static variable to false so the next instance can play the sound.

example:

```
public static bool is_playing = false;
```